# Full Calendar, How to hide the time column and list events in order

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar jQuery plugin and google calendar to create a week view of upcoming events.

I am trying to hide the times in the time column on the left and just display the events one after the other on their right day in the right order according to their time. So far I have not been able to find a solution for this and have been scouring the docs and function on [fullcalendar.io](http://fullcalendar.io/) but so far no luck. I have attached some photos to better illustrate my problem. Thanks for any help you can give.

**This is how it looks/functions now**

[image]

**This is what I am trying to accomplish**

[image]

Comment: do the elements share something like a class in common ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I was reading too far into the docs and missed one of the first implementations of the default view. Too accomplish what I am looking for in one swift stroke all I had to do is change the

defaultView: 'agendaWeek' to defaultView: 'basicWeek'

So to achieve the second picture, it would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        right: 'prev,next today',
        center: '',
        left: 'title',
    },
    defaultView: 'basicWeek',
    contentHeight: 250,
    editable: false,
    weekends: false,
    theme: true,
    columnFormat: 'ddd - D',
    eventBackgroundColor: 'rgb(27,74,110)',
    eventTextColor: 'rgb(196,241,107)',
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'API-Key',
    events: {
        googleCalendarId: 'Calendar URL',
    }
    // put your options and callbacks here
})
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try with the below code snippet.

By using CSS:- Please add below code in your page.

```
<style type="text/css">
.fc-axis
{
   display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

**OR**

By using JQuery:- Once the page load you can execute the below script or on time view change (Day/week/month).

```
$(".fc-axis").hide();
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thanks Jayesh Goyani That got rid of the axis, Now I just need to figure out how to stack the events. For example if there is an event a 10:00 -  11 am and then another at 3:00 pm I would like 3:00pm to show up immediately after the 10-11 and ignore all of the empty times in-between.

Comment: Its very difficult to achieve this thing because fullcalender is not adding event's div inside table.